# print string value before <br> tag

Tags: php

This should be simple I think, but I can't seem to get any of the similar answers working.

Basically I just want to print the value of a string before the `<br>` tag.

So if the value of `$summary` is `Title <br> more info` I just want to echo "Title".

Thanks, sorry if this has been asked 1,000 times before!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [strstr](http://php.net/strstr) to accomplish that.

```
$str = 'foo<br>bar';
echo strstr($str, '<br>', true); // foo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$summary = 'Title <br> more info';
echo explode('<br>', $summary)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

If the string is ALWAYS in that format, then this will do:

```
$vals = explode('<br>', $summary);

$before = vals[0];

echo $before;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are better than this. But just for a new approach I am writing my idea.

```
$txt = 'Title <br> more info';
echo substr($txt, 0, stripos($txt,'<br>'));
```